# How to get the same hash output in Webpack

Tags: hash, webpack, output

Is it possible to generate the exact same outputs in local and server? I am using the same Webpack version, I have removed node_modules and reinstalled all the packages with the exact same versions. But still, the outputs for both are different.

Local:

```
Hash: de5e3b914a5511a29229
Version: webpack 3.4.1
Time: 46193ms
  Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
main.js  250 kB       0  [emitted]         main
libs.js  602 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  libs
  [14] ./src/api/browser.js + 1 modules 4.9 kB {0} [built]
  [15] ./src/api/crypto.js 5.64 kB {0} [built]
  [16] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {1} [built]
  [20] ./src/api/numbers.js 2.34 kB {0} [built]
  [24] ./src/api/Coins/ETH.js 10 kB {0} [built]
  [30] ./src/const/networks.js 47 bytes {0} [built]
 [125] multi ./src/index.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
 [126] ./src/index.js + 86 modules 522 kB {0} [built]
 [203] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {1} [built]
    + 275 hidden modules
```

Server:

```
Hash: e18982fe1592d6f2dccb                                                              
Version: webpack 3.4.1
Time: 30644ms
  Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
main.js  250 kB       0  [emitted]         main
libs.js  602 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  libs
  [14] ./src/api/browser.js + 1 modules 4.85 kB {0} [built]
  [15] ./src/api/crypto.js 5.64 kB {0} [built]
  [16] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {1} [built]
  [20] ./src/api/numbers.js 2.34 kB {0} [built]
  [24] ./src/api/Coins/ETH.js 9.93 kB {0} [built]
  [30] ./src/const/networks.js 47 bytes {0} [built]
 [125] multi ./src/index.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
 [126] ./src/index.js + 86 modules 509 kB {0} [built]
 [203] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {1} [built]
    + 275 hidden modules
```